# How To Optimize Camera1 SurfaceView FrameRate

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, frame-rate

I am using Camera1 and SurfaceView to show preview and then processing that image like gray scale and thresholding. I am getting very low framerate when converting to surface to bitmap and basically image processing again taking time to process final result. Can anybody tell me which is the better way to get better fps on any view?

Answer (score 0):

After long wait and lots of research I came the solution that **OpenGL** provides best solution to run camera on high FPS and high resolution. It has many parameters to control the picture and apply multiple filters on it using **GLSL**.

Comment: OpenGL also has the advantage of being hardware-accelerated. It's heavily used in games as well (along with Vulkan, which also is available on newer versions of Android)